# Don't wait for longrunning operations ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

We have some long running operation firing when the user does something(generating several reports). We don't want the user to wait till those reports have been generated. Is there a quick way to accomplish this without having to implement a jobscheduler? Maybe using threads like this? Or is this not safe?

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MuchWork));
        thread.Start();
        return View();
    }

    public void MuchWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

See the post [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) by Phil Haack where he describes how to hack a psuedo-job scheduler while using the [IRegisteredObject interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject.aspx) to limit IIS/AppPool shut-down issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe. What about your server crashing during the operation? And the user not knowing the operation never was performed.

In general, a workflow / persistent mechanism would help with that, but you have to really think about your business / user experience case for catastrphic scenarios here.

Comment: with unsafe i meant whether it is possible that the async Thread is disposed by IIS when the calling request has ended for some time. It will indeed be necessary to have a good exception handling/logging. In our situation it would not be disastrous if the server would crash as the user would see that his report is not there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use the threadpool, or TPL so you can check status and not get thread-abused?
by 'check' i mean see how many of these requests you already have running before spinning another one.

im geussing that the result of the operation is written in some DB table , so the user can poll and see the status ?

Comment: yes, the result are reports stored in database, the user is able to view those reports when they are available.

Comment: You can achieve this using Async calls. I don't think threading is necessary based on your example. I may be missing the big picture though.. But I strongly feel this can be achieved with Async calls.

Comment: Async calls are still blocking for the current request. If i understood correctly, async calls are made for scalability, not for quicker response times for the current thread. (the view is returned when the async call is complete)

Comment: async calls are indeed used to allow for better scalability, all they do is offload the calls from ASP.NET`s threads to the thread pool. but they sync up at the PreRender if im not mistaken.